# Vagrant + Symfony2 Environment ContextErrorException Weirdness

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant

I've never had a problem with either Symfony2 or Vagrant before this point and I'm absolutely lost as to what is happening.

Without any warning my environment died completely and will only produce the following error:

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: 
file_get_contents(/Users/Paul/Sites/Project/htdocs/project-web/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception/exception_full.html.twig): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/project-web/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php line 130
```

The reason this is strange is that Symfony is referring to my local file system...

```
/Users/Paul/Sites/Project/htdocs/project-web/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception/exception_full.html.twig
```

....instead of the  box environement which is running Ubuntu, then referring to the unix filesystem location of 'Filesystem.php'...

```
/var/www/project-web/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php
```

I cannot get past this screen. I have just created a brand new environment and packaged it as a its own box, then using that box I still get this error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My first guess is you have run it locally first and the paths are in the cache. If so it should be fixed by running the following in your vagrant environment:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Add `--env=prod` if you are running the app.php rather then app_dev.php.

Comment: I actually just thought of that myself and then punched myself in the ear for being so stupid!

Comment: At times, brute-forcing it by deleting the `app/cache/[env]` folders works a little better - I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Always use the command line IN your vagrant box (via ssh), never cmd on the windows path.

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
... some auth ...
cd /your/project/path
php app/console ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Homestead with Symfony 3.1.

I had to delete `var/cache` folder from the root of my project in the host machine.

`rm -rf var/cache/` solved it.

Before, I tried out `php app/console cache:clear` with no results.